# Need help with Latent Transition Analysis

Tags: r, latent-class

I am new to this site, so my apologies if I am not asking the question the right way for this site. I am actually trying to understand Latent Class Analysis & Latent Transition Analysis. I have read a few articles. I found ProcLTA and ProcLCA in SAS, but in R I could only find poLCA package, and nothing for LTA. The webpage on which I found poLCA is below

http://sas-and-r.blogspot.com/2011/01/example-821-latent-class-analysis.html

Can someone please guide me how to do LTA in R and also what is the difference between Latent Class Analysis and Factor Analysis, as they seem very similar to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Be aware that asking for code ( / how to do it in R) is off-topic for CV. The other parts of your Q are on-topic, but you may not get an R code tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will appreciate if someone can help me understand how LCA and Factor Analysis are different, and for LTA it will be very helpful if someone can please  guide me as to what package to use for LTA and then I can do research about that package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've spent some time on this same question. I never found an R implementation, and I had a good deal of trouble uncovering the details of the SAS implementation. I think I finally found it in a technical note somewhere, but by that time I didn't need it anymore and I can't remember any of it now.

As far as the connection with factor analysis goes, it *is* factor analysis for categorical-by-categorical data. See [here](http://r2ed.unl.edu/presentations/2012/SRM/033012_RyooWu/033012_RyooWu.pdf) (page 5), among other places. Those slides also point out (although without any details) that LTA is also related to hidden Markov models. Page 19 of those slides list some free programs for fitting LTA models, including an R package that as far as I can tell doesn't exist and was never on CRAN. I did also just find an R package `ltm` that might be able to fit an LTA model. There's a [JSS paper](http://lmr.zozlak.org/SkalowanieJednoWymiarowe/Rizopoulos_2006_ltm%20An%20R%20Package%20For%20Latent%20Variable%20Modeling%20and%20IRT%20Analyses.pdf) on it by Rizopolous (2006).

edit: In case you want to roll your own in R, technical details are in the `PROC LTA` User's Guide available [here](http://methodology.psu.edu/downloads/proclcalta) for free after you register an account.

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for a while for a LTA implementation in R, so this is what I found:
LTA is the name for a particular class of discrete-time Hidden Markov Models where both the latent and the manifest variables are categorical. So, as a matter of fact, you could use R-packages dealing with these class of models, in particular "depmixs4".
However, I recently found package "LMest" which is specifically designed for LTA. It includes some of the latest results on this specific field (see e.g. recent works of Vermunt or Bartolucci). 
For example:

- Both the manifest and latent distributions can be parameterized so
  as to include individual covariates,
- Mixed LTA can be estimated
  (i.e., a mixture of Markov Chains as mixing ditribution instead of a
  simple Markov Chain),
- Viterbi's algorithm is implemented in order
  to estimate the highest posterior latent statuses

The only con I have found is that it seems to me a little slower than proc lta in SAS

Comment: Welcome to the site, @rggero. This is a little sparse for an answer here. Would you mind expanding it a bit? What makes `LMest` a particularly good choice, eg?