# Seeking examples of latent transition analysis with ordinal data and multiple subjects

Tags: r, time-series, latent-variable, latent-class, transition-matrix

**Background**

A colleague of mine has asked me for help. She has a large amount of patient data involving clinical psychological measures (e.g., questions related to specific symptoms) gathered both before and after a psychological intervention in the same subjects. She believes there to be latent states within these data – representing different phases of the disorder (during the initial or final time point) or recovery (during the final time point). She is interested in applying a statistical model capable of taking data from 9 observed variables (representing answers to questions on a 4-point ordinal scale), each measured in ~2000 participants, and estimating the latent state for each participant at time one and at time two, and further estimating the transition probabilities between states from pre-measurement to post-measurement.

**Question**

Being relatively new to this form of analysis, I am unsure how best to proceed. This sounds to me like some variant of a latent transition analysis, but I have been unable to find any examples showing how such an analysis could be implemented in any free analysis framework (e.g., R, Python). I would be most appreciative if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Your colleague can apply a latent class analysis through which a latent variable relying on the clinical psychological measures can be identified. 
You may refer to the poLCA package by Lenzer and Lewis in R:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sBIC/vignettes/LatentClassAnalysis.pdf

For the longitudinal analysis between point 1 and point 2, you may refer to the Latent Class Growth Analysis

Extensive details are provided by Feldman et al.:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2791967/

In R, you may refer to this relatively new package by Proust-Lima et al.:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lcmm/lcmm.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered two further R packages that are suitable for Latent Transition Analysis:
`LMest` (https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04448 ) and `depmixS4` (https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2015-06-09/web/packages/depmixS4/vignettes/depmixS4.pdf )

Comment: This answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/135504/93404 also recommends LMest and depmixS4 for LTA in R, although it seems they do not quite mention Latent Transition Analysis in their papers. Can you please explain how these are related?

Comment: Hi @altroware, it's been a while since I have used LTA, but I think this vignette shows the procedure nicely on page 21-27 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.04448.pdf . As the answer that you refer to says , LTA refers to transitions between different latent classes based on categorical data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't really have the choice to use Mplus or PROC LTA in SAS, since LMEST and depmixS4 don't have documentation using latent structure (LCA/LPA/LTA/...) terminology.

Also, be careful: The Hidden/Latent Markov models terminology varies between authors, so make sure to code the right LTA model.

Does someone have a code example for Latent transition analysis using LMest or depmixS4?

It could be nice to compare the results of these packages with Mplus